# How to evaluate how well some samples come from some given distributions?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, likelihood, continuous-data

I have a complicated procedure that, given an input $x$, outputs several random samples $S_i(x)$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,k\}$ (each sample consists of $n_i$ points). Each sample $S_i(x)$ follows an unknown distribution $F_i$. I wish to find $x^*$ that will make my samples $S_i(x^*)$ "look as close as possible to" a set of predefined Normal Random Variables $F^*_i =\mathcal{N}(\mu_i, \sigma_i)$. How can I measure this "looking as close as possible to some distribution"? I also wish that this metric weighs equally each $F^*_i$ and that this weighting does not depend on the parameters of $F^*_i$ ($\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$).

Initially I thought of simply calculating the likelihood of the sample, though this would work with discrete distributions, it wouldn't for continuous distributions as the likelihood of a sample is always $0$ (edit: See @amoeba answer as on why this is false).

Comment: What is the relationship between $x$ and $X$? How does the value of $x$ change the output of $X$, or can we say $X(x): x \mapsto \mathbb{R}^N$, so $x$ acts like a sample point and $X$ is a vector-valued random variable on this space?

Comment: Also, if we fix $x$ doe we always get the same $S_x$ or is $S_x$ a random vector?

Comment: @Bey the relationship between $x$ and $X$ is complicated (it arises from a numerical procedure involving other parameters and a data-set, that's why I called it a black-box) $S_x$ is a random vector

Comment: I understand that it is complicated, this is a conceptual issue. You are trying to optimize a goodness of fit measure over the input variable $x$, yet it doesn't appear that we can consider $S_x$ as a function of $x$, so such an optimization is not well defined. That's my issue with what you are trying to do. Black box optimization is totally fine, but it needs to be a valid optimization.

Comment: Also, you haven't indicated if the distribution of $S_x$ is one-to-one with $x$...if not, then you may have multiple optima.

Comment: @Bey, you are right, indeed $S_x$ is not one to one with $x$

Comment: So, doesn't that severely limit your ability to find the true maximizer $x^*$?

Comment: @Bey, I thought deeply about it again and realize that for each $x$ you have a fixed $F_i(x)$, so it is a one-to-one relationship. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: You still don't know the $F_i$ right...so your still stuck with uncertainty if which x is best.

Comment: @Bey, statistics is *all* about "uncertainty". I am not sure what point you are making.

Comment: @amoeba maybe I'm misunderstanding - OP said they wanted to optimize  the fit between the $n$ samples and a set of $n$ known distributions, where the samples are parametrized over $x$. Once we've established our goodness of fit metric, then this *would* be just a plain old calculus problem, except we don't know the samples for arbitrary $x$, so we can only optimize over the observed $x$, in which case, the $x$ acts more like an *index* than a *parameter*...

Comment: @amoeba I'm aware that we don't know $F_x$ and so must rely on $S_x$, but what I'm saying is that the set of samples that give the best fit do not imply that $x$ is the input whose $F_x$ are expected to yield the closest fit. It's a question of whether estimating $x$ based on maximizing the fits of $S_x$ is a consistent estimator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goodness of fit of $S_x$ to $X^*$ can be assessed in a number of ways: the [Cramér-von Mises statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93von_Mises_criterion), the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test), or [chi-square statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit#Pearson.27s_chi-squared_test) would be common choices, and there are certainly [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit). If we knew something about the distribution of $S_x$, or about your specific goals or performance criteria, then it might be possible to say more.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: So, in the new formulation of the question, each $x$ results in not just one sample, but a family of $k$ samples $S_i(x)$, each from a different distribution depending on $x$ and $i$. In this case, you can apply a goodness-of-fit measure (such as those listed in my answer) for each $i=1,\dots,k$ and then combine those measures in some way, e.g., by summing them up over $i$.

Comment: +1. Consider editing into your answer your own suggestion to use $(\hat\mu-\mu)^2+\lambda(\hat\sigma-\sigma)^2$ as a possible goodness of fit metric.

Answer (score 4):

> I thought of calculating the likelihood of the sample, but this would work with discrete distributions. But for continuous distributions the likelihood of a sample is always $0$.

**This is a misconception.**

If you have a point $x_i$ and a probability distribution $f(x)$, then the likelihood that this point comes from this distribution is defined as $f(x_i)$. If $f(x)$ is the PDF of a normal distribution, then $f(x)\ne 0$ for any $x$.

If you have an iid sample $S=\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$, then the likelihood of it coming from the same distribution is $\prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i).$

I think this should be enough to get you going. Note that if $f(\cdot)$ is normalized to integrate to $1$, then values $f(x_i)$ tend to be small and when multiplied together quickly become close zero. That is why we are usually working with log-likelihood instead of likelihood: $$\log\Big(\prod_{i=1}^nf(x_i)\Big)=\sum_{i=1}^n\log f(x_i).$$

---

**Having said all that, it seems that in your case you should compute some goodness-of-fit statistic and not the likelihood.** The difference is illustrated in the first comment by @BrentKerby.

Comment: you say that values $f(x_i)$ tend to be small and when multiplied together will become close to zero, does this still hold for normal distributions with very low $\sigma$?

Comment: I actually thought of doing this, but I thought it would not work because I actually have not one but several outputs samples, each of which I want to approximate it to a different distribution (in my case different normals with different $\sigma$). I think this method will biase my choice

Comment: I don't think the likelihood is a good choice here, because, supposing the reference distribution (for $X^*$) is $N(\mu,\sigma)$ samples $S_x$ which concentrate themselves near $\mu$ with standard deviation as low as possible will produce the highest likelihood (The degenerate distribution at $\mu$ will maximize it); it does not require that $S_x$ have a scale and scape resembling $N(\mu,\sigma)$, as we would desire.

Comment: Consider two simple distributions $X=\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ and $Y=\mathcal{N}(0, 2)$. And assume that I have a sample $x$ and $y$ from each respectively. $x=1$ and $y=2$. In this case the likelihood of $x$ and $y$ will be different right? but because both of them were off by $\sigma$ on each case I would assume that the "likelihood" of each "should" be the same.

Comment: @Nuno Re your first comment: It's usually better to work with log-likelihoods because it's numerically more stable. Does not matter what your $\sigma$ is. Re your following comments: I agree, comparing likelihoods like that does not make sense. See also Brent's comment (+1).

Comment: @Brent, yes, that's a good point. It looks like likelihood is not the right tool for the OPs problem (also given what he wrote in a later comment here). But I am sure you will agree that what OP wrote about likelihood being zero for continuous variables is a misconception.

Comment: @amoeba, I think Nuno might mean that, as $x$ varies, each random vector $S_x$ follows a different distribution, say, with components having cdf $F_x$, while on the other hand, $X^*$ has a fixed cdf $F$, and we want to find the value of $x$ that makes $F_x$ as "close" to $F$ as possible. Nuno, is that what you meant?

Comment: On the other hand, you could use maximum likelihood to estimate the mean and variance of each $S_x$ and then compare these estimates to the known $\mu$ and $\sigma$, e.g., we could use $(\hat\mu-\mu)^2+\lambda(\hat\sigma-\sigma)^2$ to measure the goodness of fit, for some choice of $\lambda$ determining the relative importance of the variance vs. the mean. In the case of a normal distribution, $\hat\mu$ and $\hat\sigma$ have simple known formulas: they are just the sample mean and sample variance without Bessel's correction.

Comment: @BrentKerby This is indeed what I meant exactly but with a slight modification: "as $x$ varies, each random vector $S_x$ follows a different distribution (from which we can only estimate this true cdc $F_x$ by $(F_n)_x$ the empirical distribution function), while on the other hand, $X^*$ has a fixed cdf $F$, and we want to find the value of $x$ that makes $(F_n)_x$ as "close" as possible to $F$.

Comment: @amoeba, I agree completely.

Comment: Both of you really made me understand where I was thinking incorrectly and how to think correctly about this. But now I look at my question and feel it is inadequate. Should I rephrase it completely? Should I create a new one? I especially liked the simple solution of using $(\mu-\hat{\mu})^2+\lambda(\sigma-\hat{\sigma})^2$ to assess how well my sample "looks" like a $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$

Comment: @Nuno, I'd say edit this question to clarify your problem (rephrasing is okay as long as you are still talking about the same thing). But I am still unsure about the relevance of your comment above about two normal distributions. Why do you suddenly consider two distributions $X^*$ and $Y^*$? In your question you only ask about one.

Comment: @NunoCalaim you're missing a key issue: $x$ does not define a unique $S_x$, so how do you now that the $S_x$  this is the best fit with $X^*$ is due to the choice of $x$ and not simply sampling variation (i.e., $F_x$ vs $(F_n)_x)$

Comment: @all I edited the question